# How do you import multiple pages of a PDF into Inkscape CLI?

Tags: inkscape, automation

I'm trying to import a PDF (actually hundreds of PDFs) into Inkscape Command Line for export into PDF again. This is in an attempt to clean up a PDF with some compatibility issues with another piece of software I'm using.

The Inkscape Command Line documentation does not make it clear if this is even possible, but it is possible within the application (not command line interface); you can open a PDF and re-export it with all of its pages.

I've tried lots of commands and there is a promising argument `--pdf-page`

```
inkscape --pdf-page=- IN.pdf --export-type=pdf --export-filename=OUT.pdf --export-area-page
```

In that command, you can see I've passed a dash in, but this causes an error

```
Cannot parse integer value “-” for --pdf-page
```

When using an actual integer, it will only do a single page.

Please tell me there's something I'm missing here, Inkscape MUST have this feature (if it doesn't, maybe you could steer me in the direction of a command line tool which can clean up PDFs)

Thank you

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Inkscape's multi-page PDF import functionality is fairly new. I wouldn't be surprised if you can't actually do this from the command line yet, TBH. I tried searching but [the documentation](https://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Using_the_Command_Line) I found says "--pdf-page=PAGE: Imports the given page of a pdf file. Numbering starts with 1." - which would seem to suggest that it can only import single pages.

Comment: @BillyKerr Ah, that's a shame to hear. Thanks, I ended up using Ghostscript instead which ended up being much cooler and probably quicker